# Visualforce link to create new Account/Contact/

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I have a custom VisualForce page and would like via javascript to get the url to create a new account/contact.

I know I can do the following in the main apex code but I want to do something dynamically.
Create New Account

What is the easiest way to get the url to create a new object via javascript?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you want to create an Account and/or Contact using Javascript or just provide a link to the "new account" page.
If you want to give a link to create a new account you can use the object prefix '001/e' for accounts and '003/e' for contacts.

Comment: I am looking for a link. Is there no other api call that can be made with the given object name? I could have swore there was...

Comment: If not what are the links for opportunities, leads, and cases?

Comment: There are lists like [this one](http://www.salesforcefast.com/2012/02/salesforce-standard-object-record-id.html). That have all prefixes for standard objects. Those never change. The other option is to run [describe calls](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) in apex and render them as javascript variables in the visualforce page.

Comment: Well if they don't change I will just use the list there. Thanks

Comment: Checked your question while editing and found out your code was not being displayed. 
Added how to do it as an answer along with the link to standard object prefixes. Mark it as an answer if it is useful for you. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in Javascript (if your script tag is inside a visualforce page):

```
var newAccountEndpoint = '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.New)}';
var newOpptyEndpoint = '{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New)}';
```

Or as I stated before refer to [pre made list of standard salesforce object prefixes](http://www.salesforcefast.com/2012/02/salesforce-standard-object-record-id.html)

Comment: Is there any way to invoke a call back or know when this new object has been crated if it is created in a separate window?

Comment: One solution for this can be to [pre populate a field](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-do-i-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-layout) with a known token and monitor the record created with a given parameter token using [force.com streaming](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/).